# What are OpenGL ES gotchas between iOS simulator and iOS device?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios-simulator

This is a bit of a broad questions and the aim is to list most common errors when developing an OpenGL ES enabled application on the iOS simulator and then finding out that it does not behave the same on the device.

Gotchas:

- OpenGL ES on iOS Simulator and iOS device **may NOT have the same OpenGL ES supported feature set**.
- iOS device has OpenGL ES **Tile Based Rendering** while iOS Simulator has **Direct mode.**

Note: The OpenGL ES app should be OpenGL ES conformant.